# Obj-C - how to cast id into GLfloat[]

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I've got a `NSMutableArray` of simple arrays of `GLfloat`.
That's how I build it in Swift:

```
var arrays = NSMutableArray()
for(i=0; i<arraysCount; i++) {
    var array:[GLfloat] = []

    // fill the array

    arrays.appand(array)
}
```

But how can I get my arrays by index in Objective-C?
`[arrays objectAtIndex:index]` gives me an ID, but how to cast it into array of GLfloat?

I need to use arrays of GLfloat, because this arrays must to be drawn and I'm sending them into `glBufferData()`.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make any sense whatsoever. id is an Objective-C object. CGFloat is a number. They are totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-c you cannot add simple C types to `NSMutableArray`s `NSMutableArray` can only contain objective-c objects. It is therefore likely that the array you get when you call `[arrays objectAtIndex:index];` is an array of `NSNumber`s or `NSValue`s.

In objective c you can use C style arrays e.g. `int myArr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` or `NSArray`s but you cannot mix them. Therefore an `NSArray` of `int`s would be `NSArray *myArr = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5]` where `@1` is an `NSNumber` object with an `intValue` of 1.

So to convert your array to an array of `float`s you can do something like:

```
float otherArr[(int)myArr.count];
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.count; i++) {
    NSNumber *num = myArr[i];
    otherArr[i] = myArr.floatValue;
}
// Voilia a C style array of floats
```

This is where Swift can confuse when you get to objective-c because this is all done implicitly I believe.